# OpenVPN connection in Ubuntu not allowing internet access with new broadband router

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I am currently facing a strange issue with my OpenVPN setup on Ubuntu, and I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on the problem. I have an OpenVPN (.ovpn) configuration file that I use to connect to a VPN, and in Windows, I have the OpenVPN application which connects to the VPN without any issues.

However, after switching to a new broadband router, I'm encountering a problem when connecting to the VPN in Ubuntu. While I can successfully access internal IP addresses such as SSH and SCP, the internet is not working, and even internal websites like Jira cannot be accessed. Strangely, I don't experience this issue on Windows with the same router.

I reached out to my broadband provider's support team, and they suggested that if the VPN is working fine on Windows, there might be some configuration issue specific to Ubuntu causing the problem.

Here are some additional details about my setup:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04
- OpenVPN version: 2.5.5

I tried to import the VPN config file into network manager and enable the ""Use this connection only for resources on its network" but still the same issue, I followed the below link for this

[No internet access when VPN connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29183/no-internet-access-when-vpn-connected)

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What brand is the new router?