Ubuntu server with access to internet and working VPN, but no internet access over the VPN
I have a microserver with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installed. It has access to internet, and I have a VPN set with OpenVPN. I can succesfully connect to the VPN and the server from another laptop in a external internet network. But I do not have internet in the laptop when connected to the vpn. I want to access internet through the vpn.
I have read a lot online, but I can still not figure it out.

It does not look like a DNS problem, because neither a ping from laptop to google.com nor 8.8.8.8 works.
No firewall issue in the server, because it does not work with ufw disabled.

I have checked the routing, which should be the problem, but I can not find the issue.
Configuration information:
Openvpn server.conf config:
local 192.168.1.100
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
#redirect-gateway ipv6


The vpn is configured on 10.8.0.0/24

Output of route -n in the server:





Destination
Gateway
Genmask
Flags
Metric
Ref
Use
Iface




0.0.0.0
192.168.1.1
0.0.0.0
UG
100
0
0
eno1


10.8.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0
0
0
tun0


192.168.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0
0
0
eno1


192.168.1.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0
0
0
eno1


192.168.1.1
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.255
UH
100
0
0
eno1




Output of route -n in the laptop (when connected to vpn)




Destination
Gateway
Genmask
Flags
Metric
Ref
Use
Iface




0.0.0.0
10.8.0.1
0.0.0.0
UG
50
0
0
tun0


0.0.0.0
192.168.2.1
0.0.0.0
UG
600
0
0
wlp2s0


10.0.3.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
0
0
0
lxcbr0


10.8.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
50
0
0
tun0


83.X.X.X
192.168.2.1
255.255.255.255
UGH
50
0
0
wlp2s0


169.254.0.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.0.0
U
1000
0
0
wlp2s0


192.168.2.0
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.0
U
600
0
0
wlp2s0


192.168.2.1
0.0.0.0
255.255.255.255
UH
50
0
0
wlp2s0



83.X.X.X is the ip of the server, I replaced the full address by X for security reasons. In addition, if it helps, the router to which the server is connected only has the ssh port open. It is not a problem of the router to which the laptop is connected, because it does not work either from other networks.
What else can I check? Suggestions are highly appreciated

Ok so this solution seems to work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29183/no-internet-access-when-vpn-connected
But with that option enabled, I have internet, but no access to the server through ssh. What is the reason behind it? My networking knowledge does not go that far
Edit: no, I have internet but my ip is the same as with the vpn deactivated...
